# WCF / Silverlight requests timing out after 30 secs with WebRequest.RegisterPrefix

Tags: silverlight, wcf, timeout, webrequest, connection-timeout

I have a WCF webservice and a SL4 client which always times out after 30secs with a ConnectionTimeout exception.

After much time spent messing with WCF timeout params etc, I found that the problem was being caused by a call to WebRequest.RegisterPrefix when my application starts up.

This call is performed so i can receive FaultExceptions in the SL client, and display the text of the problem to my users. This is a recommended solution by Microsoft:

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556(v=vs.95).aspx

If i remove this line, then great, I can upload big files to the server and it doesn't time out (90 secs plus - timeout is set to 2mins).

Does anyone know why this is timing out after 30secs, and more importantly, whether there is a way to increase the timeout? Or is this a bug?

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug.

You can increase the Timeout in your 'web.config'

Comment: Are you talking about wcf config timeouts? As mentioned in my post above, I have spent alot of time changing these timeouts with no effect. My timeouts are set to 90secs. This is honoured if i remove the WebRequest.RegisterPrefix call (which switches my app to using the clientHTTP stack instead of the browser stack).